# Show the filename column from the Compare-Object SideIndicator result?

Tags: powershell

I wanted to compare the content of two .CSV files with the other files generated from a different DNS server.

C:\OldDNS.CSV

```
Name          Type Value                              
----          ---- -----                              
corporate.net SOA  ns1.parkingcrew.org                
corporate.net A    185.53.177.52                      
corporate.net MX   mail.h-email.net:5                 
corporate.net TXT  v=spf1 ip6:fd1b:212c:a5f9::/48 -all
corporate.net NS   ns1.parkingcrew.com                
corporate.net NS   ns2.parkingcrew.net
```

C:\NewDNS.CSV

```
Name          Type Value                              
----          ---- -----                              
corporate.net SOA  ns1.parkingcrew.net                
corporate.net A    185.53.177.52                      
corporate.net MX   mail.h-email.net:0                 
corporate.net TXT  v=spf1 13.55.73.22 -all
corporate.net NS   ns1.parkingcrew.net                
corporate.net NS   ns2.parkingcrew.net
```

Script:

```
$outFile = 'C:\differences.csv'
$reference = Get-Content -Path C:\OldDNS.CSV | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
$difference = Get-Content -Path C:\NewDNS.CSV | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $reference -DifferenceObject $difference |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject |
            Set-Content -Path $outFile
Invoke-Item $outFile
```

How can I get the additional column which shows the filename where there is the difference on each line?

Because the below result is quite confusing and I wonder if it is possible to show the filename where these changes are detected:

```
InputObject                                        SideIndicator
-----------                                        -------------
corporate.net SOA  ns1.parkingcrew.net                 =>                    
corporate.net SOA  ns1.parkingcrew.com                 <=           
corporate.net MX   mail.h-email.net:5                  <= 
corporate.net TXT  v=spf1 13.55.73.22 -all             <=
corporate.net MX   mail.h-email.net:0                  => 
corporate.net TXT  v=spf1 ip6:fd1b:212c:a5f9::/48 -all <=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the filename at the beginning, it might be easiest to just store it and then reference it later. Something like this

```
$reference = @{
    Path    = 'C:\OldDNS.CSV'
    Content = Get-Content -Path 'C:\OldDNS.CSV' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
}

$difference = @{
    Path    = 'C:\NewDNS.CSV'
    Content = Get-Content -Path C:\NewDNS.CSV | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
}

$alldifferences = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $reference.Content -DifferenceObject $difference.Content

$alldifferences |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } |
        Select-Object *,@{n='File';e={$difference.Path}}

$alldifferences |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } |
        Select-Object *,@{n='File';e={$reference.Path}}
```

Or simply store the path and do the content gathering in-line.

```
$reference = 'C:\OldDNS.CSV'

$difference = 'C:\NewDNS.CSV'

$alldifferences = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $reference | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $difference | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() })

$alldifferences |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } |
        Select-Object *,@{n='File';e={$difference}}

$alldifferences |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=’ } |
        Select-Object *,@{n='File';e={$reference}}
```

Comment: thank you for the update and the suggestion, may I know why in the second example, the Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }  is the same for both $difference & $reference?

Comment: It shouldn’t be. It was a copy/paste accident

Comment: No problem. Looks like I had them reversed as well

Comment: Thanks a lot @Doug.